# Can I do a cargo build with debug symbols as well as release flag?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am debugging my cargo project. I build it using `--release` flag generally. But when I saw the stack trace in gdb, it was not very readable. I figured out that I could [create debug symbols](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-profile-sections) with `debug=true` in Cargo.toml.

Can I still use `--release` flag with cargo build ? Are these not contradicting? This is what the terminal help for the flag says -

> --release Build artifacts in release mode, with optimizations

I ask this for clarity beforehand as a debug run takes several hours for me to hit the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling with `--release`, and having a `Cargo.toml`

```
[profile.release]
debug=True
```

And will indeed include debug symbols as well as perform optimizations. The two are not contradictory.

The `[profile.release]` table of your `Cargo.toml` only tells `cargo` what configuration options you'd like to use when you pass the `--release` flag. Other options include tuning LTO, optimization levels, and enabling/disabling rpath.

Comment: Thanks @kbknapp. I had done it the same way without any issues.